# Type mismatch java.io.Serializable and GenTraversableOnce

Tags: scala, parsing

I'm trying to get a parser to take a sequence of colon-seperated words and convert them into an array.

Here's an SSCCE.

```
import util.parsing.combinator._

class Element {

  def getSuper() = "TODO"

}

class Comp extends RegexParsers with PackratParsers {
  lazy val element: PackratParser[Element] = (
    "foo") ^^ {
    s => new Element
  }

  lazy val list: PackratParser[Array[Element]] = (
    (element ~ ";" ~ list) | 
    element ~ ";") ^^ 
  {
    case a ~ ";" ~ b => Array(a) ++ b 
    case a ~ ";" => Array(a)
  }
}

object Compiler extends Comp {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    println(parseAll(list, "foo; foo; foo;"))
  }
}
```

It's not working and it's not compiling, if it was I wouldn't be asking about it. This is the error message I'm getting. Is there a way to convert from Serializable to GenTraversableOnce?

```
~/Documents/Git/Workspace/Uncool/Scales$ scalac stov.scala
stov.scala:19: error: type mismatch;
 found   : java.io.Serializable
 required: scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[?]
    case a ~ ";" ~ b => Array(a) ++ b
                                                    ^
one error found
```

Comment: Maybe, I'm not sure what the difference between those two is, but it also gives me a compiler error `stov.scala:17: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Comp.this.Parser[Array[_ >: ScalaObject]]
 required: Comp.this.PackratParser[Array[Element]]
    element ~ ";") ^^ 
                   ^
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suspicion goes on the `|` combinator.

The type of `(element ~ ";" ~ list)` is `~[~[Element, String], Array[Element]]` and the type of `element ~ ";"` is `~[Element, String]`.

Thus when applying the `|` combinator on these parsers, it returns a `Parser[U]` where `U` is a supertype of `T` (`[U >: T]`).

Here the type of `T` is `~[~[Element, String], Array[Element]]` and the type of `U` is `~[Element, String]`.

So the most specific type between `Array[Element]` and `String` is `Serializable`. 
Between `~[Element, String]` and `Element` its `Object`. That's why the type of `|` is `~[Serializable, Object]`.

So when applying the map operation, you need to provide a function `~[Serializable, Object] => U` where `U` is `Array[Element]` in your case since the return type of your function is `PackratParser[Array[Element]]`.

Now the only possible match is:

```
case obj ~ ser => //do what you want
```

Now you see that the pattern you're trying to match in your map is fundamentally wrong. Even if you return an empty array (just so that it compiles), you'll see that it leads to a match error at runtime.

---

That said, what I suggest is first to map separately each combinator:

```
lazy val list: PackratParser[Array[Element]] =
    (element ~ ";" ~ list) ^^ {case a ~ ";" ~ b => Array(a) ++ b} |
    (element ~ ";") ^^ {case a ~ ";" => Array(a)}
```

But the pattern you are looking for is already implemented using the `rep` combinator (you could also take a look at `repsep` but you'd need to handle the last `;` separately):

```
lazy val list: PackratParser[Array[Element]] = rep(element <~ ";") ^^ (_.toArray)
```

Comment: Thanks, I got it working with. `rep(element ~ ";") ^^ {s => s.map(y => y match {case x ~ _ => x}).toArray}`.

Comment: @JoshuaSnider Why not simply make use of `<~` ? `rep(element <~ ";")` is a `Parser[List[Element]]`. IMO much more simpler :)

Comment: Because I'm new to Scala and the thought hadn't occurred to me?